# How do I ignore the primary record if any of the secondary record is matching in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables A and B. Table A is the master product table. Table B contains the product foreign key reference as well as the start and future expiry date. I would like to fetch only those products which are ONLY having ALL future expiry date. Even if those product records have atleast one start date and remaining all future dates, I would NOT want to query those records.
So, how do I fetch these records in a Oracle SELECT query?

```
SELECT * 
FROM PRODUCT A, PRODUCT_RELATION B 
WHERE A.ROW_ID = B.PROD_ID 
AND B.START_DATE (+) < SYSDATE 
AND A.NAME = 'Zinc'
```

When I use the above query, it gives me the records which are expired even though there are future dated records. I want to ignore all the records even if there is one expired record in product relation table

Comment: Better post your input and expected output. Also your attempt so far. Looks like you want `JOIN` query with proper `WHERE` clause.

Comment: SELECT * FROM PRODUCT A, PRODUCT_RELATION B WHERE A.ROW_ID = B.PROD_ID AND B.START_DATE (+) < SYSDATE AND A.NAME = 'Zinc'
When I use the above query, it gives me the records which are expired even though there are future dated records. I want to ignore all the records even if there is one expired record in product relation table.

Comment: Please *edit your question* to add further useful information.  Comments are for ephemeral: it should be possible to delete a comment without spoiling the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to approach this is to get all the rows which match your selection criteria, then filter out the ones with dates you don't want.

Use the subquery factoring construct to avoid querying the tables more than once.

```
with sqf as (SELECT *
              FROM PRODUCT A, PRODUCT_RELATION B 
              WHERE A.ROW_ID = B.PROD_ID 
              AND A.NAME = 'Zinc' )
select * 
from sqf
where sqf.row_id not in (select x.row_id
                         from sqf x
                         where x.START_DATE < SYSDATE)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot !
I just learned a new concept in Oracle called 'Subquery Factoring'.